# How to solve scss conflict between NuxtJS and Vuetify 2.0

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to upgrade an existing NuxtJs project to use the new vuetify version 2.0.
NuxtJS uses the 'node-sass' package for processing sass/scss files that are being used. Vuetify 2.0 depends on the package 'sass' and requires the 'node-sass' package to NOT be present so as not to conflict.

I have already tried removing the package 'node-sass' and a myriad of other possible configurations.
The problem gets even more complex by the use of the package '@nuxtjs/style-resources', which is used to expose the scss files to components. This packages seems to be utilizing the unwanted 'node-sass' with no obvious options to bypass it.
The closest to a working result that I have got is by declaring a custom loader as demonstrated here https://codesandbox.io/s/kk70v7217

nuxt.config.js:

```
    import Fiber from "fibers";
    import Sass from "sass";

    const customSass = {
      implementation: Sass,
      fiber: Fiber
    };

...

    build: {
        loaders: {
          scss: customSass
        }
      }
```

When not using '@nuxtjs/style-resources', the scss files seem to be loaded, but not exposed to the vuetify components,
with errors as 'undefined variable $accent-color' in every variable occurrence.
When using '@nuxtjs/style-resources' for the files to be exposed, it insists in looking for the unwanted 'node-sass'.

Is there a way to make ends meet in using vuetify 2.0 with nuxtjs and style-resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [vuetify-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module). The current version is `1.0.1` and is using `vuetify v2`

After you install this module you can check the `vuetify` version with `npm list vuetify`

Comment: Thank you for the reply Nicu. I have already tried this but keep getting the error: \\node_modules\\@nuxt\\vue-app\\template\\App.js: Cannot resolve "vuetify/dist/vuetify.css", although comparing it to a clean, working, new nuxt-app the paths are correct. Also the dependency conflict with package @nuxtjs/style-resources is not resolved... I guess there is always the option to move all the content to a fresh installation (and not use style-resources) but that wouldn't be a real solution as the project grows....

Comment: It turns out that the latest version of @nuxtjs/style-resources is patched to work just fine with vuetify-module without using node-sass. To conclude, using vuetify-module and the latest style-resources resolves all issues.